# Attempted relative import in non-package for optional package

Tags: python, package

I tried to run :

```
import numpy as np
from dipy.reconst.multi_voxel import multi_voxel_fit
from dipy.reconst.base import ReconstModel, ReconstFit
from scipy.special import hermite, gamma
from scipy.misc import factorial, factorial2
import dipy.reconst.dti as dti
from warnings import warn
from dipy.core.gradients import gradient_table
from ..utils.optpkg import optional_package

cvxopt, have_cvxopt, _ = optional_package("cvxopt")
```

But it gives ValueERROR:ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
Thank You !

Comment: The `..utils.optpkg` is to blame. How does your tree of directories look like?